# How do you symbolise a 32-bit raster in ArcObjects?

Tags: raster, arcmap, arcobjects, symbology

For rasters that are *above* 16-bit - you cannot apply a colormap. So what is happening when you symbolise in ArcMap a 32 bit raster - it's certainly possible. I'm trying to emulate this funcitonality in ArcObjects - but at the moment I'm getting a bit muddled.  Can anyone lend a hand here?

**CODE - not working.**

```c#
IRasterDataset rasterDataset = null;
IRasterLayer rasterLayer = new RasterLayerClass();
rasterDataset = GeodatabaseManager.RasterWorkapaceEx.OpenRasterDataset("fooRaster");


IRasterStretchColorRampRenderer rasterStretchColorRampRenderer = new RasterStretchColorRampRendererClass();
IRasterRenderer rasterRenderer = (IRasterRenderer)rasterStretchColorRampRenderer;
IRasterStretch rasterStretch = (IRasterStretch)rasterStretchColorRampRenderer;
rasterStretch.StretchType = esriRasterStretchTypesEnum.esriRasterStretch_MinimumMaximum;
IRaster raster = (IRaster)rasterDataset.CreateDefaultRaster();
rasterRenderer.Raster = raster;

IAlgorithmicColorRamp colorRamp = new AlgorithmicColorRampClass();
colorRamp.Size = 255;
colorRamp.FromColor = CreateRGBColor(0, 0, 255);
colorRamp.ToColor = CreateRGBColor(255, 0, 0);
bool createColorRamp;
colorRamp.CreateRamp(out createColorRamp);

rasterStretchColorRampRenderer.BandIndex = 0;
rasterStretchColorRampRenderer.ColorRamp = colorRamp;

rasterRenderer.Update();
rasterLayer.CreateFromDataset(rasterDataset);
ILayer layer = (ILayer)rasterLayer;
ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.AddLayer(layer);
```

Comment: Precisely what have you tried and where are you stuck?  Can you **edit** your question to include a code snippet, please?